# Class Name in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, class-names

I wonder about dynamically changing of class name in .NET application. For example WindowsForms10.SysTreeView32.app.0.19fd5c7. The last string "19fd5c7" would change, but I don't know what makes it changing. Is it the version, the GUI modification, environment, OS or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually based on the hash code of the current app domain.